# How to get first 300 rows of Google sheet via gspread

Tags: python, google-sheets-api, gspread

**Set-up**

I create a Pandas dataframe from all records in a google sheet like this,

```
df = pd.DataFrame(wsheet.get_all_records())
```

as explained in the [Gspread docs](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html).

---

**Issue**

It seems Python stays in limbo when I execute the command since today. I don't get any error; I interrupt Python with `KeyboardInterrupt` after a while.

I suspect Google finds the records too much; ±3500 rows with 18 columns.

---

**Question**

Now, I actually don't really need the entire sheet. The first 300 rows would do just fine.

The docs show `values_list = worksheet.row_values(1)`, which would return the first row values in a list.

I guess I could create a loop, but I was wondering if there's a build-in / better solution?

Comment: Does [`batch_get()`](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#gspread.models.Worksheet.batch_get) work for you?

Comment: In fact, if you have a single range of cells, [`get()`](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#gspread.models.Worksheet.get) should also work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the values from 1st row to 300 row from a sheet in Google Spreadsheet.

  - From `I suspect Google finds the records too much; ±3500 rows with 18 columns.`, you want to retrieve the values from the columns "A" to "R"?
- You want to convert the retrieved values to the dataFrame.
- You want to achieve this using gspread.

In order to achieve this, I would like to propose the following sample script.

In this answer, I used the method of `values_get`.

#### Sample script:

```
spreadsheetId = "###"  # Please set the Spreadsheet ID.
rangeA1notation = "Sheet1!A1:R300"  # Please set the range using A1Notation.

client = gspread.authorize(credentials)
spreadsheet = client.open_by_key(spreadsheetId)
values = spreadsheet.values_get(rangeA1notation)
v = values['values']
df = pd.DataFrame(v)
print(df)
```

#### Note:

- Please set the range as the A1Notation. In this case, when "A1:R300" instead of "Sheet1!A1:R300" is used, the values are retrieved from the 1st tab in the Spreadsheet.
- When "A1:300" is used, the values are retrieved from the column "A" to the last column of the sheet.
- When the 1st row is the header row and the data is after the 2nd row, please modify as follows.

  - From

    ```
      df = pd.DataFrame(v)
    ```
  - To

    ```
      df = pd.DataFrame(v[1:], columns=v[0])
    ```

#### Reference:

- [values_get](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#gspread.models.Spreadsheet.values_get)

Answer (score 1):

I used **openpyxl** package.

`import openpyxl as xl`

`wb = xl.load_workbook('your_file_name')>` 
`sheet = wb['name_of_your_sheet']`

Specify your range.
`for row in range(1, 300):`

Now you can perform many opertions e.g this will point at row(1) & col(3) in first iteration
    `cell = sheet.cell(row, 3)`

if you want to change the cell value 
   `cell.value = 'something'`

It's has pretty much all of it.
Here is a link to the docs: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/